# get child nodes xml attribute value

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

```
<test>
    <acc id="1"> acc1 </acc>
    <acc id="2"> acc2 </acc>
    <acc id="3"> acc3 </acc>
    <acc id="4"> acc4 </acc>
</test>
```

For example, if I want to take the value of each `<acc>` element:

```
var iAccs = xdoc.Descendants("test").Elements("acc").Select(p => p.Value);
List<string> myList = new List<string>();
foreach(string p in iAccs)
{
    myList.Add(p);
}
```

But how to substract all the attribute "id" values of each `<acc>` elements?

Comment: Do you mean "extract"?

Comment: To get both in one query : var iAccs = xdoc.Descendants("test").Elements("acc").Select(p => new {
   value = (string)p,
   id = (int)p.Attribute("id")
}).ToList();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily get this using LINQ-to-XML:-

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(@"You XML file path");
List<string> result = xdoc.Descendants("acc")
                          .Select(x => (string)x.Attribute("id")).ToList();
```

Or if you prefer query syntax then:-

```
List<int> result2 = (from x in xdoc.Descendants("acc")
                     select (int)x.Attribute("id")).ToList();
```